# argument order in numpy.apply_along_axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I would like to apply a function to each row of a 5x1 numpy array. The function I am applying takes two arguments, and I would like the elements of the array to enter as the second argument, not the first. I have been using `numpy.apply_along_axis()`. Looking at the documentation for this function, it doesn't seem like it's possible.

Is there anyway to do this without explicitly defining a new function with the argument order reversed? I'm just curious. Here's the example I've been messing around with.

```
import numpy as np
tmp = np.random.rand(5,1)
lol = lambda first, second: float(first)/second
print tmp
np.apply_along_axis(lol, 1, tmp, second=1) #works but I don't want this
np.apply_along_axis(lol, 1, tmp, first=1)  # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to tweak your example to make it a bit more interesting

```
In [188]: tmp=np.arange(6.).reshape(2,3)
In [189]: lol=lambda first, second: np.sum(first)/second
```

So with 2d tmp we can apply it along either axis

```
In [190]: np.apply_along_axis(lol,0,tmp,2)
Out[190]: array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5])

In [191]: np.apply_along_axis(lol,1,tmp,2)
Out[191]: array([ 1.5,  6. ])
```

Another `lambda` cleanly switches the arguments:

```
In [192]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda x,y:lol(y,x),0,tmp,2)
Out[192]: 
array([[        inf,  2.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.66666667,  0.5       ,  0.4       ]])
```

(same as `2/tmp`; axis doesn't matter)

The extra layer of function call doesn't change execution speed much (switching the arguments increases time, but I want to focus on the effect of the extra `lambda`).

```
In [195]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(lol,1,tmp,2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 103 us per loop

In [196]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(lambda x,y:lol(x,y),1,tmp,2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 105 us per loop
```

There's nothing magical or extra efficient about using `apply_along_axis`; you (or we) could write an iteration that does the same thing.

Let's compare 2 expressions, an `apply_along_axis` and an equivalent list comprehension:

```
In [213]: np.apply_along_axis(lol,0,tmp,2)
Out[213]: array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5])

In [214]: np.array([lol(tmp[:,i],2) for i in range(tmp.shape[1])])
Out[214]: array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5])

In [215]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(lol,0,tmp,2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 132 us per loop

In [217]: timeit np.array([lol(tmp[:,i],2) for i in range(tmp.shape[1])])
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.1 us per loop
```

`apply_along_axis` is slower, probably because it is trying to be more general.  It may be more convenient, but it isn't obviously more 'efficient'.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible! But the function itself is called directly with the data being the first argument (see [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.10.0/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L91)), so you need another layer of abstraction to change the arguments: for example with a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
def swapelements(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(array, *args, **kwargs):
        # Insert the array as second=array:
        kwargs['second'] = array
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

np.apply_along_axis(swapelements(lol), 1, tmp, first=1)
```

```
array([[  6.24582532],
       [  1.14800413],
       [  1.87634432],
       [ 14.31209963],
       [  2.47123623]])
```

with `tmp` being `[[ 0.16010694], [ 0.871077  ], [ 0.53295122], [ 0.06987095], [ 0.40465577]]`

---

If you operate on a `5x1` array why do you use `apply_along_axis`? You could achieve the same by just using:

```
result = 1. / tmp
```

Your second axis only contains one element.